# SwiftUI Started giving two errors after update: Extraneous argument label and Initializer 'init(_:)' requires the types and String.Character be equal

Tags: swiftui, tradingview-api

I'm using the tradingview lightweight chart in SwiftUI and I've been using it like so for many months:

```
chart.applyOptions(options: ChartOptions(layout: LayoutOptions(backgroundColor: "#111111")))
```

I updated Xcode last week, and now the code above gives these errors:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ChartView.LayoutOptions' (aka '_PlatformViewRepresentableLayoutOptions') to expected argument type 'LayoutOptions?'

Extraneous argument label 'backgroundColor:' in call

Initializer 'init(_:)' requires the types '_PlatformViewRepresentableLayoutOptions.Element' (aka '_PlatformViewRepresentableLayoutOptions') and 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') be equivalent
```

I have looked over the library and ChartOptions definitely has layout property:

```
public struct ChartOptions: Codable {
    public var layout: LayoutOptions?
...
}
```

and LayoutOptions takes backgroundColor as an argument:

```
public struct LayoutOptions: Codable {
    
  public var backgroundColor: ChartColor?
...
    }
```

Can anyone think of any reason(s) why these issues are coming up now? Everything looks good to me

I have tried to look at the examples provided by TradingView themselves, but they  all use the same method as used above or different method that also gives the same error.

Comment: There seems to be another `LayoutOptions` type and the compiler isn't able to choose the correct one. Try this: `ChartOptions(layout: LightweightCharts .LayoutOptions(backgroundColor: "#111111"))`

Comment: @Timmy Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately Type 'LightweightCharts' has no member 'LayoutOptions', so this doesn't work. but now I also see this note in gray: 1. 'setupChart(options:)' declared here (LightweightCharts.LightweightCharts (private)) 

I am not sure what this means exactly